# "Sys is undefined" error in databinded page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, data-binding, formview, sys

I have a page with a formview that is generating the "Sys is undefined" error.

This is the only page that have this problem, so it is not an web.config error or IIS configuration error.

The page contains a formview with the three templates (item, insert and edit). There is also some dropdownlist controls inside that make databinding by itself to populate its list items.

PROBLEM AND SOLUTION!: 
After carefully unmount my page by pieces and mounted again step by step in order to catch the source of the problem I got that the DropDownLists that are databinded to the page (the page was acting as the datasource) were the error generators.

I was so "idiot" that handled the Dropdownlists's ObjectDataSource.ObjectCreating event to set the page instance as the ObjectInstance, but didn't handled the ObjectDisposing to cancel the object instance dispose. And (voilà!), the "Sys is undefined" error arises!!!

This is a case where a butterfly flaps its wings in Japan and generates an earthquakes in America!!!

I hope no one else after reading this post will get caught by this type of error.

Comment: Thank you. You've probably saved me several hours of frustrated debugging.

Comment: Thanks too. Although I already spent several hours of frustrated debugging, you saved me some more.